# Java stops at method

Tags: java

I'm having a very wierd problem with java.

```
        System.out.println("finding bounds");
        bounds = findBounds(shapes);
        System.out.println("all bounds compared");
```

I have this method called findBounds. It runs fine hundreds of times, but at a certain point the program just stops before even reaching the first line of the method. When i say stops, i mean the program is still running, but never gets any further. Here is the begining of the findBounds method:

```
 private Rectangle2D findBounds(List<MapShape> shapes) {
        System.out.println("in bounds method");
```

Last thing that gets printed is "finding bounds".
I have checked that `shapes` is not null. I am also not running out of memory. When i stop the program i get this line:

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 880
```

Any help would be appreciated. Tell me if you need me to provide more of the code.

entire method:

```
private Rectangle2D findBounds(List<MapShape> shapes) {
    System.out.println("in bounds method");
    if (shapes == null || shapes.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("shapes null or 0");
        return new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,0,0);
    }
    System.out.println("finding initial");
    double maxX = shapes.get(0).getBounds2D().getMaxX();
    double maxY = shapes.get(0).getBounds2D().getMaxY();
    double minX = shapes.get(0).getBounds2D().getMinX();
    double minY = shapes.get(0).getBounds2D().getMinY();

    int total = shapes.size();
    int actual = 0;

    System.out.println("starting loop");
    for(MapShape s : shapes){
        actual++;
        if(actual%1000 == 0){
            System.out.println("finding bounds "+actual+"/"+total);
        }
        Rectangle2D bounds = s.getBounds2D();
        double shapeMaxX = bounds.getMaxX();
        double shapeMinX = bounds.getMinX();
        double shapeMaxY = bounds.getMaxY();
        double shapeMinY = bounds.getMinY();

        if(shapeMaxX>maxX){
            maxX = shapeMaxX;
        } if(shapeMaxY>maxY){
            maxY = shapeMaxY;
        }if(shapeMinX<minX){
            minX = shapeMinX;
        }if(shapeMinY<minY){
            minY = shapeMinY;
        }
    }

    return new Rectangle2D.Double(minX,minY,maxX-minX,maxY-minY);
}
```

Comment: Does this method have any loops?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. While creating it you may find the issue yourself.

Comment: Provide the code for the method

Comment: even if it does have loops, it should print `in bounds method` assuming it is the first statement in the method.

Comment: What version of Java are you running? Because that error was fixed in Java 8u40: [JDK-8061621](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061621)

Comment: There is a loop, but System.out.println("in bounds method"); is the first line.

Comment: where do i post the entire method? I can't here in the comments

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49456009/edit) your question.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: Try latest Java 8 version. If it works there, you know it's a bug in Java. [Java 7 is end-of-life since April 2015](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml), i.e. almost **3(!)** years ago.

Comment: check this as well https://github.com/puniverse/quasar/issues/240.

Comment: Tried running with latest versions of java 8 and 9. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. There was an infinate recursion in the method that contained findBounds. Somehow java dident crash, but just stoped executing.